# restart virtual machine via azure python sdk

Tags: python, azure

microsoft created an anti-human api for azure. How can I restart virtual machine via azure python sdk? some demo code would be great.

Comment: Take a look here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/master/tests/test_servicemanagementservice.py#L1852. Not sure if it applies to VMs but I think it does apply to Cloud Services.

Answer (score 2):

Although this is old, here's a sample code:

```
from azure.common.credentials import ServicePrincipalCredentials
from azure.mgmt.compute import ComputeManagementClient    
credentials = ServicePrincipalCredentials(client_id=clientid, secret=secret,
                                              tenant=tenantid)
compute_client = ComputeManagementClient(credentials, subscriptionid)
vm_restart = compute_client.virtual_machines.restart(resource_group_name, vm_name)
vm_restart.wait()
vm_instance = compute_client.virtual_machines.get(resource_group_name, vm_name)
```

where *vm_instance* is the VM object containing all its confg information.

Comment: Thanks all the same, even though I have no chance to give it a try.

Comment: now instead `restart`, must use `begin_restart`